# JMS sending slow

Tags: java, jms, glassfish-3

I have JMS configured on glass fish domain that facilitates communication between two applications on two domains. How can i look into the JMS queue after the issue has happened. One message was sent very slow and took like 6 secs and then 14 seconds and in between everything else was fine. i want to know what delayed it to this extent usually it is in millisecs.
the server.log only has entry when the msgs server starts and when it shuts down so its not useful.

there are some broker files in the imq directory but some are log.txt files with close and accepting connection. Is there any way to know what was happening at that time in the queue that it took so much time

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for the delays. Such as the number of messages sent and the rate that they are being consumed. Most likely it is related to the MDB consuming the messages (on the consumer application). Make sure that you have enough MDBs running concurrently on the consumer domain. (This is all configurable on the web server admin on the activation spec)

Other issue could be the connectivity, but in case there was a connectivity problem you would have seen something in the logs most likely.

Comment: thanks for the reply, otc. we are using Spring's router to send and an extension of Spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer. We log the time when we actually send and log the time when the messageListener's onMessage() method is invoked. So we know when it was received by the consumer. There is nothing much going on at the moment there are other message but not that many to cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your MDB code, the consumers. You may have a code which needs more time to execute, thus blocking resources (threads) on the server for some time (e.g external system call with longer timeouts etc).